# Windows Phone App.xml compile, but throw error on missing type when try runnig the app

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, mvvm-light

I have an soulution With 2 Project. One With Windows phone and one PortableClassLibrary.

In the PortableClassLibrary I have implemented the ViewModelLocator part who give Access to the ViewModel's used by my View's in the Phone Project.

In the app I have:

```
   <Application xmlns:vm="clr-namespace:PortableClassLibrary.ViewModel;assembly=PortableClassLibrary" />    

<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
      <vm:ViewModelLocator x:Key="Locator" d:IsDataSource="True" />
    <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries></ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

Everything work fine, and it compile without any errors.

When I start the Phone emulator it crash when it try load App.xaml and Informa that "The type ViewModelLocator" was not found"

How can that be that it find it when working in App.xaml, but can't when I try to run it?

Comment: How do you use locator?